# Flutter different screen layout in different phone

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, text-styling, flutter-text

[image]
[image]

I was facing this problem when I try to open my app on different phone. The text seem moved away and different size. Hereby I included my code. What should I do t make it flexible? As you can see mostly I design the layout using height and width and it was just working fine on the first picture. However, the text seem oversized when viewed on another phone.

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
  left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 10),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
  width: 420,
  child: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
           Container(
           width: 80,
           child: Text(
           "Intervention Number",
           textAlign: TextAlign.left,
           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
           ),
           ),
           SizedBox(
             width: 8,
           ),
           Text(snapshot.data!.totalIntervention,
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
               ),
               SizedBox(
                   width: 50,
               ),
               Container(
                 width: 60,
                 child: Text(
                    "Success Rate",
                 textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                 ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                   width: 5,
                ),
                Text(
                   snapshot.data!.sucessIntervention + '%',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                ),
                ],
               ),),
          ],
      );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refer to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0O_qDZ48F7o , and you can try to get the screen's height and width by this

```
MediaQuery.of(context).size.height

MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a FittedBox to keep the text fitted inside the container

```
 Flexible(
   child: FittedBox(
     fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
     child: Text(
        "Intervention Number",
         maxLines: 1,
       ),
     ),
   ),
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. It will make it flexible but only limit it to one row. so its no enough